# Can I copy someone else's wordpress theme and website layout and build my own wordpress website same as theirs?

Tags: html, css, json, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I know this sounds illegal however one of my friend owns a wordpress website and brags about it's security BS that one cannot copy a wordpress web layout/theme however my little experience in web development says that it is possible to copy someone else's wordpress web layout/theme and use it as your own.

Now he has challenged me to copy his theme and make my own website on wordpress and I have his consent to do so.

So, is it possible to perform such activity and if yes then how?

I tried looking for some WP Plugins but no luck.

> I also tried using Figma plugin **"HTML to Figma by Builder.io"** but when I imported the .json file, it was all messy and not worth anything.

Comment: What if you use CTRL+SHIFT+I to open up inspect and copy the code? Or just CTRL+s to save it and them modify the code? or ook at the source files

Comment: That way I can only copy the frontend design right? There will be no code behind it describing buttons and everything, right?

Comment: You can make it look the same, or at least very similar, by copying the CSS and any related HTML/JS, but much of the functionality of a Wordpress site is in the backend - e.g. getting stuff from the database and manipulating it using PHP so the short answer is : no you can't completely.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the HTML and theme style, but not the PHP. You can rebuild the front-end by creating a new WordPress theme and doing everything from scratch, but there's no automatism to do what you say.

If your friend has a PHP filter that modifies Wordpess behavior, you will never be able to replicate it. If you want to replicate the front-end only, you can do it from scratch.

In summary, if you are looking for an automatic tool to do it quickly, forget it.

Answer (score 0):

Use CTRL+SHIFT+I to open up inspect and copy the code. Or just CTRL+s to save it and then modify the code. For the backend, you will need to hack.